# What's the 26" tire that is the same width as 700×35c

Tags: 26-inch

I have a 26" front wheel and 700c rear wheel. I put 35c on my rear wheels and I'd like to put the same tire witdh Infront. What 26" tire is the same as 700×35c?

Comment: Your 26" wheel should also have a metric value, maybe on your old tyre. Those seem to be more precise.

Answer (score 8):

35mm is 1.378". That's the same as 1.375 for our purposes. So you'd get a 26x1.375 tyre.

But tyre sizing isn't that precise, and anyway is affected by tread and the width of the rim you put it on. To get a similar feel, the same make and model in 26x1.375 will be closest, assuming the same rim width.

Even then, the smaller wheel diameter and different frame will mean a different sensation as you pass over rough bits.

There's no real need to put the same tyre front and rear; in your case you may want a bigger tyre at the front to offset the smaller wheel.

Note also the existence of rare 26" wheels with fractional rather than decimal widths. These aren't compatible with tyres giving their widths in decimal

Comment: Concur - I have one bike with a 28mm front tyre and a 2" rear tyre.

Comment: @Criggie I haven't gone that extreme but ran 28 front and 35 rear by choice when I had a child seat fitted.  And for commuting bikes I regard 28-35mm as interchangeable.  OTOH my MTB has 2.3" at the front and 2.1" at the back